# Using Rails API

Tags: ios, json, ruby-on-rails

I'm learning iOS Development with the Treehouse Library. Building an app that gets information from a json API.

In the Treehouse API page all the posts are under a parent called "Posts" (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/)

```
posts: [
{
  id: 22198,
  url: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website",
  title: "Using GitHub Pages To Host Your Website",
  date: "2013-08-16 09:30:20",
  author: "Matt West",
  thumbnail: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/github-pages-feature-150x150.jpg"
},
{
  id: 22196,
  url: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/running-tests-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip",
  title: "Running Tests in Ruby on Rails &#8211; Treehouse Quick Tip",
  date: "2013-08-15 14:30:48",
  author: "Jason Seifer",
  thumbnail: null
},
```

The API from my Rails app doesnt have a Parent (http://www.soleresource.com/releases.json)

```
[
{
  shoe_name: "Air Jordan 4 "Green Glow"",
  release_date: "2013-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
  shoe_colorway: "Dark-Grey/Green-Glow",
  shoe_price: "160",
  url: "http://www.soleresource.com/releases/8.json"
},
{
  shoe_name: "Nike Barkley Posite",
  release_date: "2013-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
  shoe_colorway: "Gamma-Green/Black",
  shoe_price: "235",
  url: "http://www.soleresource.com/releases/17.json"
},
```

In order to get the app to work I have to call the Parent (posts), like this:

```
 self.upcomingReleases = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];
```

How can I "wrap" my API under a Parent? (My model is called "Releases")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, if you are using your rails app as a REST API, you should definitely use [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). It will let you specify everything for your JSON responses, like *metadata* or *roots*

Here is a RailsCast for it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

Comment: or, in your rails controller do something like: `render json: releases: @releases`